# Google translate CSS Style Spanish

Tags: css, styles, translate

I am looking to style my menu with google translate. Menu works great in English. Menu is 700px wide. When it translates to Spanish it pushes it all down..
So my question: Is there a way to change the font size of text when it goes to Spanish?

I have tried this and it did not work.

```
 .nav a {
 font-size: 18px;
 }
  em:lang(es)) .nav a{
 font-size: 14px;
 }
```

I dont know if the code is actually seeing that because Google translate is using js.. 
Also this is an html site. Not wordpress or anything.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for because I see no examples or sort of, so I blindly say to try to add `display:inline-block;` to the class

Answer (score 1):

You need add `lang` attribute to your html:

```
<nav>
  <li lang="es"><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
  <li lang="en"><a href="#">English</a></li>
</nav>
```

and css:

```
nav li[lang|="es"]  a{
   font-size:  14px;
}
nav li[lang|="es"]  en{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

[here is some example](http://jsfiddle.net/aamjpbou/).

You just need to change the `lang` attribute value of `li` when it goes to Spanish.